# Can I store a big hexadecimal value in Long datatype in Java?

Tags: java, int, long-integer, mac-address

Mac address is 6 bytes long(12 digit or 48bits in length).
Long can hold 8 bytes of data but still I am not able to store following mac addresss in a long data variable?

```
Long mac=(long) 0xffffffffffff;
```

Why is it happening?
What is the best datatype to store mac address data type(I want to store in base10 format)?

Comment: You need to add 'l'/'L' at the end to indicate it is a long integer, other wise it will be interpreted as normal int data

Comment: @JordiCastilla This does not appear to be a duplicate of the question you indicated.

Comment: @khelwood might not be the same but IMHO it is broader and includes the solution to this question... Anyway, you can vote to reopen it and see what comunity thinks, I don't have the final or the true word but I can't vote as duplicate in java without closing question...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a `long` value but an `int`. Just add `L` to your number

```
Long mac= 0xffffffffffffL;
```

To quote Oracle

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l;
>   otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit 1.

**As for your question** about which datatype to chose, any can be good as long as it holds the necessary 48bits.

Noteworthy, java returns a byte array in order to get the harware address in [NetworkInterface#getHardwareAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress--), but states that it is '*usually*' a mac address.

Comment: The type cast to long is kinda redundant.

Comment: @archilius edited thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it as Long value by adding a `L` at the end:

```
Long mac = 0xffffffffffffL;
```

You can find more information of the `L` in the [Java SE Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) (3.10.1. Integer Literals).

Comment: So casting to long does not work or what?

Comment: You do not need to cast to Long, because you defined it already as Long by appending the `L`

Comment: @DJ The question is "what" are you casting to long? From the original statement, you were casting an int value. However, the value was too large for int data type. Hence the exception.